# CSS ignoring explicit div background

Tags: html, css

I've successfully configured the featured-top and footer elements of my CSS so that they are displaying correctly.  My only problem is that I can't get rid of the white line between the two elements.  When I use Google Chrome to Inspect Element I don't so where this could be occurring?

```css
.agentpress-gray .featured-top.featured-top {
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px #666; 
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px #666;
    background-color: #ddd;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px #666;
    clear: both;
    margin: 0 auto 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 20px;
    width: 920px;
}
```

AND footer element:

```css
.agentpress-gray #footer {
    background-color:#000;
}
```

Comment: There's a `20px` margin at the bottom of `.featured-top` element. Simply remove that by `.featured-top { margin-bottom: 0; }`

Comment: Okay, that makes sense.  I've updated the question to remove the link and display the problematic CSS.  Not sure how I missed that but it did the trick.  Thanks @HashemQolami

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
.featured-top {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```